# Creating a QModelIndex

Tags: qt, qmodelindex

I have spent the last week struggling to create a QModelIndex given a row and a column.

Alternatively, I would settle for changing the value of row() in an already existing QModelIndex.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:

```
QModelIndex nIndex = QAbstractItemModel::createIndex(1, 2);
int b = nIndex.row();
qInfo() << "b" << b;
```

Fails with error:

```
cannot call member function ‘QModelIndex QAbstractItemModel::createIndex(int, int, void*) const’ without object
         QModelIndex nIndex = QAbstractItemModel::createIndex(1, 2);
                                                                  ^
```

The goal at hand is this:

I have a function:

```
void MyClass::doStuff(QModelIndex index)
```

Inside that class, I essentially do the following:

```
if (index.column() != 1)
{
    int a=index.row();
}
```

So my goal is to call that function from a different class and pass it a QModelIndex, but for that index to have been created with a row/column I specify.

Answer (score 15):

I'm not sure this is what you want, but you can just create a `QModelIndex` with the method `QAbstractItemModel::index(row, column)` ( http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#index )!? On the other hand that seems to be to simple for you to struggle with it for so long, maybe explain a little bit more.

Example:

```
QAbstractTableModel *model = ...;

// then you can do something like
QModelIndex nIndex = model->index(1,2);
int b = nIndex.row();
qInfo() << "b" << b;
```

Comment: I think the real struggle comes from being new to Qt. I think what you've said is what I want and tried; however, the struggled continues. I've updates my initial post to have some more info. Thank you!

Comment: I changed my answer, the first link was wrong sorry, you can use the `QAbstractItemModel::index` (not `createIndex`, that is protected), and if you're new you can't just call it like that it's not static. You need a valid "data model" where you store the data and on **that** call the `index` method. I guess you have a model somewhere, what else is the point of getting a `QModelIndex`?

Comment: @MetalWing I've added a short example to my answer, but it depends what you actually use as a model I have no clue. :)

Answer (score 9):

You can get a new index from the appropriate model, using its `index()` method.

If you already have an index from the model, with the same parent as your desired index, then you can get another index using the `sibling()` method of that index:

```
void MyClass::doStuff(const QModelIndex& index)
{
    // get the value at row zero, same column
    const QModelIndex header = index.sibling(0, index.column());
}
```

The index itself is immutable once created - you can't change its row, column or parent (other than by invalidating it with changes to the model behind its back).